# How to determine changes in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I would like to log changes in a data.frame:

In the `original` dataframe I have the following structure:

```
library(dplyr)
library(compare)

origianl <- data_frame( name = c('John','Tim','Allan','Mitch'),

                          A = c(0,1,1,0),

                          B = c(1,0,0,1),

                          C = c(0,0,0,0),

                          D = c(1,0,0,1))

#> data.frame(origianl)

   name           A           B           C           D
1  John           0           1           0           1
2   Tim           1           0           0           0
3 Allan           1           0           0           0
4 Mitch           0           1           0           1
```

Here for instance John plays for B and D.

In the `changed` dataframe I have the following structure:

```
changed <- data_frame( name = c('John','Tim','Allan','Mitch'),

                                A = c(1,0,1,0),

                                B = c(0,0,0,0),

                                C = c(0,1,0,1),

                                D = c(1,0,0,1))

#> data.frame(changed)
   name           A           B           C           D
1  John           1           0           0           1
2   Tim           0           0           1           0
3 Allan           1           0           0           0
4 Mitch           0           0           1           1
```

Here for instance John changed teams and now plays for A and D.

There are couple of constraints:

I check `original` on daily basis. Player may play for multiple teams or for one and they can switch teams. They are assigned to at least one team.

What I have tried is to write a function which logs the changes in two specific columns `when` `from`

The desired output table may look like this, which is basically the `changed` with two additional columns logging the change:

```
#> data.frame(new_original)
   name           A           B           C           D  from    when
1  John           1           0           0           1   B     2017-01-01
2   Tim           0           0           1           0   A     2017-01-01
3 Allan           1           0           0           0   NA     NA
4 Mitch           0           0           1           1   B     2017-01-01
```

What I have tried so far:

```
my_func <- function(origianl, changed) {
# Get the difference
 difference <- anti_join(changed, origianl)
# find the changes in the original data
  differ <- origianl[origianl$name %in% difference$name, ]

# check whether condition is satisfyied
if (nrow(differ) == nrow(difference) &&
  nrow(anti_join(changed, origianl)) > 0)

{
 new_original <-
  cbind(changed, from = names(which(
    compare(difference[2:ncol(difference)], differ[2:ncol(differ)], allowAll =
              TRUE)$detailedResult == FALSE, when = Sys.Date()
  )))

 }

 return(new_original)
}

new_original = my_func(origianl, changed)
```

Which results in `arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3`
from the cbind commmand. Not sure how to get to the ideal output

Comment: try using a `merge()` or `dplyr::full_join()` instead of your `cbind()` to get your changes integrated into your dataframe

Comment: How do you get `when`?

Comment: ^ Please show how is `when` column being calculated

Comment: Hi @Sotos @David, Im sorry, its `when = Sys.Date()`

Comment: Hi there, @HiThere. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible vectorized approach using base R. You haven't specified how is `when` column calculated (is this just the current date?) but here is how `from` could be calculated pretty easily

```
indx <- which((origianl[-1] - changed[-1]) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
changed[indx[, "row"], "from"] <- names(changed)[-1][indx[, "col"]]
changed
#    name A B C D from
# 1  John 1 0 0 1    B
# 2   Tim 0 0 1 0    A
# 3 Allan 1 0 0 0 <NA>
# 4 Mitch 0 0 1 1    B
```

Comment: Hello David, thank you for that nice solution. May I ask you to show how to include the `Sys.Date()` aka `when` into your code.

Comment: @HiThere You could add `changed$when <- Sys.Date() ; changed[is.na(changed$from), "when"] <- NA`. Btw, I'm working here with data.frames, not tibbles.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `when` is picked up by `Sys.time()`, then,

```
library(dplyr)

f1 <- function(x, y){
  d4 <-left_join(y, x, by = 'name')
  d5 <- d4[grepl('.x', names(d4), fixed = TRUE)]
  d6 <- d4[grepl('.y', names(d4), fixed = TRUE)]
  l1 <- apply(d5 - d6, 1, function(i) names(i)[i == -1])
  y$from <- sub('\\..*', '', unlist(ifelse(lengths(l1) == 0, NA, l1)))
  y$when <- Sys.time()
  y$when[is.na(y$from)] <- NA
  return(y)
}

f1(origianl, changed)

#   name A B C D from                when
#1  John 1 0 0 1    B 2017-03-14 15:37:59
#2   Tim 0 0 1 0    A 2017-03-14 15:37:59
#3 Allan 1 0 0 0 <NA>                <NA>
#4 Mitch 0 0 1 1    B 2017-03-14 15:37:59
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you get the when, but this should work for from:

```
origianl <- as.data.frame(origianl)
id <- sapply(1:nrow(origianl), function(x) i[which( origianl[x,]==1)][!(i[which( origianl[x,]==1)] %in% i[which(changed[x,]==1)])])
origianl$from <- sapply(id,function(x) ifelse(length(x)==0,NA,x))
```